# How to define Kafka storage path on Confluent CLI

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I use standard home path for confluent center

```
 export CONFLUENT_HOME=/home/kafka/confluent/confluent-7.4.0
```

Unfortunately, I can not change path to store data. I found Kafka config in path and set up needed storage

```
cat /home/kafka/confluent/confluent-7.4.0/etc/kafka/server.properties | grep log.dir
log.dirs=/storage/kafka-logs
```

Than I restart Confluent Platform, however Path is wrong

```
./confluent local services start
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only, NOT for production usage. See more: https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html
As of Confluent Platform 8.0, Java 8 is no longer supported.

Using CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /tmp/confluent.430818
Starting ZooKeeper
ZooKeeper is [UP]
Kafka is [UP]
Starting Schema Registry
Schema Registry is [UP]
Starting Kafka REST
Kafka REST is [UP]
Starting Connect
Connect is [UP]
Starting ksqlDB Server
ksqlDB Server is [UP]
Starting Control Center
Control Center is [UP]
```

Unfortunately, web interface can not allow location of storage.

[image: Web interface]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think the confluent CLI lets you modify any settings, since it is only meant for local quick-start, and not to emulate a production ready setup, as mentioned in the logs.

You can use [Docker Compose, instead](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.4.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml), and you would add an env-var `KAFKA_LOG_DIR` with a volume mount.

Comment: Thank you, @OneCricketeer, maybe this is solution, but how to really use this CLI in my local installation? I have simple local installation https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/zip-tar.html and it working perfectly, but important parameters can not changed. I try to use ./ confluent context list in order to update and receive answer - Context None found. Second possible to manage default setting ./confluent kafka acl list, answer is Error: Kafka REST URL not found, but in reality REST API found, I show screen on question.

Comment: ./confluent kafka topic list give me "No session token found, please enter user credentials. To avoid being prompted, run "confluent login". - login to what? Login to confluent cloud need credit card firstly, even to free plan. What this is trash? To change configuration on my local installation I must set up my credit card to Confluent company? Or what login mean this command line?

Comment: Can I get you remote access to my server, if you have interesting to see local installation of Confluent platform and how is possible to manage it.

Comment: I already have a local setup using the linked repo... As answered, don't even bother using the CLI. It's not required. Just use Docker compose. Issues/Questions about the CLI should be posted at https://github.com/confluentinc/cli/issues